# default selected option with angular directives

Tags: html, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive

I have a select HTML tag from two options, where I'd like to choose first option by default. In select I use angular directives: ng-change and ng-model. I'm trying to do that with adding `selected = "selected"` to one of my options. Below I show my html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="surveysFilter.dateKind"
                    ng-change="setcheckedDateKind(surveysFilter.dateKind)">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Generate</option>
                <option value="2">Answer</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

How should I do this? I would be grateful for help ;)

Comment: You can give scope value as **$scope.surveysFilter.dateKind = '1';** in controller level.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="surveysFilter.dateKind"
                    ng-change="setcheckedDateKind(surveysFilter.dateKind)">
                <option value="1" ng-selected="true">Generate</option>
                <option value="2">Answer</option>
            </select>
</div>
```